# Spring Integration Pub sub sample project "Could not autowire. No beans of 'PubSubTemplate' type found."

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm checking out some of Spring Integration with GCP pub sub and I've cloned their sample project. I'm getting a warning / error in my IDE which I'm struggling to understand.

Basically in this class https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/6c95a16f7e6ad95404b4f992b5f46340e831e5cb/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-integration-pubsub-json-sample/src/main/java/com/example/WebController.java#L47

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.SenderConfiguration.PubSubPersonGateway;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;

/**
 * Provides REST endpoint allowing you to send JSON payloads to a sample Pub/Sub topic for
 * demo.
 *
 * @author Daniel Zou
 */
@RestController
public class WebController {

    private final PubSubPersonGateway pubSubPersonGateway;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ProcessedPersonsList")
    private ArrayList<Person> processedPersonsList;

    public WebController(PubSubPersonGateway pubSubPersonGateway, SenderConfiguration.PubSubProjectGateway pubSubProjectGateway ) {
        this.pubSubPersonGateway = pubSubPersonGateway;
    }

    @PostMapping("/createPerson")
    public RedirectView createUser(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("age") int age) {
        Person person = new Person(name, age);
        this.pubSubPersonGateway.sendPersonToPubSub(person);
        return new RedirectView("/");
    }

    @GetMapping("/listPersons")
    public List<Person> listPersons() {
        return this.processedPersonsList;
    }
}
```

I have the following error

```
Could not autowire. No beans of 'PubSubPersonGateway' type found.
```

Could someone please explain why I'm getting this error / warning and if its something I need to be concerned with? FYIW, The project will compile and run correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an IDE inspection issue, nothing more. That `PubSubPersonGateway` is a special `@MessagingGateway` bean which is not understood by IDE. Probably better to raise an improvement ticket against that IDE to let them know that Spring Integration inspection should be improved.